# Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 2, 3, 3], expected input[15, 6, 256, 256] to have 2 channels, but got 6 channels instead

Tags: python, neural-network

I am working on a problem for Image Inpainting. For this, I am using the Unet as a generator. So it is working fine on Gray Image (Single channel), when I tried to move it to 3 Channels (RGB), it throws the error. Below is the my model code.

```
class DualConv3x3(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, activation):
        super().__init__()
        self.gating_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv_1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.gating_2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv_2 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.activation = activation
        
    def forward(self, x):
        gating = self.gating_1(x)
        x = self.conv_1(x)
        x = self.activation(x) * torch.sigmoid(gating)
        gating = self.gating_2(x)
        x = self.conv_2(x)
        x = self.activation(x) * torch.sigmoid(gating)
        return x
    
class EncoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.dual_conv = DualConv3x3(in_channels, out_channels, activation=nn.ReLU())
        self.pooling = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2)

    def forward(self, x):
        skip = self.dual_conv(x)
        out = self.pooling(skip)
        return out, skip
    
class DecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.up_conv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2)
        self.up_conv_gated = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2)
        self.dual_conv = DualConv3x3(in_channels, out_channels, activation=nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2))
        
    def forward(self, x, skip):
        gating = self.up_conv_gated(x)
        x = self.up_conv(x)
        x = F.leaky_relu(x, negative_slope=0.2) * torch.sigmoid(gating)
        x = torch.cat((skip, x), dim=1)
        x = self.dual_conv(x)
        return x
    
class UNetEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.b1 = EncoderBlock(in_channels, 64)
        self.b2 = EncoderBlock(64, 128)
        self.b3 = EncoderBlock(128, 256)
        self.b4 = DualConv3x3(256, 512, activation=nn.ReLU())

    def forward(self, x):
        x, skip_1 = self.b1(x)
        x, skip_2 = self.b2(x)
        x, skip_3 = self.b3(x)
        x = self.b4(x)
        return x, [skip_1, skip_2, skip_3]

class UNetDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.b3 = DecoderBlock(512, 256)
        self.b2 = DecoderBlock(256, 128)
        self.b1 = DecoderBlock(128, 64)
        
    def forward(self, x, skip_conns):
        x = self.b3(x, skip_conns[-1])
        x = self.b2(x, skip_conns[-2])
        x = self.b1(x, skip_conns[-3])
        return x

class UNet(nn.Module):
    """ U-Net as proposed in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf with
    3 downsampling operations instead of 4 due to memory restrictions.
    """
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = UNetEncoder(in_channels)
        self.decoder = UNetDecoder()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(64, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x, skip_connections = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x, skip_connections)
        x = self.conv(x)
        # clipping didn't work here and produced constantly black outputs
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x

class DiscriminatorBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 
                              out_channels, 
                              kernel_size=3, 
                              padding=1, 
                              stride=2)
        self.conv = nn.utils.spectral_norm(self.conv)
        self.bn = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        """ It is advised to use leaky relu in discriminator
        https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-stable-generative-adversarial-networks/
        """
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = F.leaky_relu(x, negative_slope=0.2)
        x = self.bn(x)
        return x
        
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.block1 = DiscriminatorBlock(2, 32)  # Input has 3 channels
        self.block2 = DiscriminatorBlock(32, 64)
        self.block3 = DiscriminatorBlock(64, 128)
        self.block4 = DiscriminatorBlock(128, 256)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(256 * 16 * 16, 1)
        self.linear = nn.utils.spectral_norm(self.linear)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.block1(x)
        x = self.block2(x)
        x = self.block3(x)
        x = self.block4(x)
       # x = x.view((x.shape[0], -1))
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x

BATCH_SIZE = 15
EPOCHS = 1
size = 256

class ImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_paths):
        super().__init__()
        self.image_paths = image_paths
        self.transform = albumentations.Compose([
             albumentations.Resize(size, max_size)
        ])
        self.cutout = albumentations.Cutout(num_holes=1,
                                            max_h_size=100,
                                            max_w_size=100,
                                            p=1.0,
                                            fill_value=1)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, index):        
        image = cv2.imread(self.image_paths[index])
       # image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) / 255.0  # Load RGB images
        image = self.transform(image=image)['image']
      
        image_cutout = self.cutout(image=image)['image']
        # Convert images to PyTorch tensors and normalize them
        image = transforms.ToTensor()(image)      
        image_cutout = transforms.ToTensor()(image_cutout)       
        # Create a binary mask (1 for non-cutout regions, 0 for cutout regions)
        mask = (image_cutout != 1.0).float()
       # print(mask.shape)
        return image, image_cutout, mask   




ds_train = ImageDataset(image_paths)

train_loader = DataLoader(
    ds_train,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()
)


reconstruction_loss = nn.L1Loss()

def wasserstein_loss(y_pred):
    """ Maximises the earth-mover distance
    """
    return torch.mean(y_pred)

def adv_loss_disc(y_pred_real, y_pred_fake):
    return - wasserstein_loss(y_pred_real) + wasserstein_loss(y_pred_fake)
    
def adv_loss_gen(y_pred_fake):
    return -1 * wasserstein_loss(y_pred_fake)

generator = UNet(2,1).to(device)
discriminator = Discriminator().to(device)

optim_gen = torch.optim.Adam(generator.parameters(), lr=0.0002)
optim_disc = torch.optim.Adam(discriminator.parameters(), lr=0.0002)

def train(epochs,
          gen,
          disc,
          optim_gen,
          optim_disc,
          train_loader,
          print_every_iteration=50):
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        gen_adv_losses, gen_rec_losses, gen_losses, disc_losses, acc_reals, acc_fakes = [], [], [], [], [], []
        for i, (x, x_blacked_out, mask) in enumerate(train_loader):
            x, x_blacked_out, mask = x.to(device).float(), x_blacked_out.to(device).float(), mask.to(device).float()
            x_blacked_out = torch.cat([x_blacked_out, mask], dim=1)
            gen.train()
            disc.train()

            # train discriminator only every 10 iterations since he is way too strong
            if i % 10 == 0:
                fake_imgs = gen(x_blacked_out)
                y_pred_real_imgs = discriminator(x)
                y_pred_fake_imgs = discriminator(fake_imgs)
                acc_real = torch.mean((y_pred_real_imgs >= 0) * 1.0).item()
                acc_fake = torch.mean((y_pred_fake_imgs < 0) * 1.0).item()
                disc_loss = adv_loss_disc(y_pred_real_imgs, y_pred_fake_imgs)
                optim_disc.zero_grad()
                disc_loss.backward()
                optim_disc.step()

            acc_reals.append(acc_real)
            acc_fakes.append(acc_fake)
            disc_losses.append(disc_loss.item())

            # train generator
            optim_gen.zero_grad()
            fake_imgs = gen(x_blacked_out)

            y_pred_fake_imgs = discriminator(fake_imgs)
            gen_adv_loss = 0.005 * adv_loss_gen(y_pred_fake_imgs)
            gen_rec_loss = reconstruction_loss(fake_imgs, x)
            gen_loss = gen_adv_loss + gen_rec_loss
            optim_disc.zero_grad()
            optim_gen.zero_grad()
            gen_loss.backward()
            optim_gen.step()
            gen_adv_losses.append(gen_adv_loss.item())
            gen_rec_losses.append(gen_rec_loss.item())
            gen_losses.append(gen_loss.item())

            if i % print_every_iteration == 0 and i != 0:
                print(f"EPOCH {epoch}/{EPOCHS}, ITERATION {i}")
                print(f"gen_adv_loss: {round(np.mean(gen_adv_losses), 6)} gen_rec_loss: {round(np.mean(gen_rec_losses), 6)} gen_loss: {round(np.mean(gen_losses), 6)} disc_loss: {round(np.mean(disc_losses), 6)}, acc_real: {round(np.mean(acc_reals), 6)}, acc_fake: {round(np.mean(acc_fakes), 6)}")
                fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 10))
                ax[0].imshow(x_blacked_out[0, 0].cpu().reshape((256, 256)), cmap="gray")
                #ax[1].imshow(fake_imgs[0].detach().cpu().permute(1, 2
                plt.show()
                                
        torch.save(gen.state_dict(), "./gen_model")
        torch.save(disc.state_dict(), "./disc_model")
```

I am getting this error when run with 3 channels, I cannot figure out what might be the issue, but I know it is from my model Architecture. Please help me out with this error.

Correct solution with code.

Comment: What is the error?